# Run time adding control in C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am making an application in which I want to add buttons on panel from my main form dynamically. If I have 10 items in List then that many buttons will be generate on panel from main form. But when I try to do that one then it shows me error that Control.Invoke required.

Please anyone suggest me how to add controls...??

```
private void CheckOrderListEntry(Workorder workorder)
    {
        int ticketID = workorder.TicketID;
        int index = 0;
        int lastIndex = _workorderList.Count;
        bool isExist = false;

        for (index = 0; index < lastIndex; index++)
        {
            int existingTicektId = _workorderList[index].TicketID;

            if (ticketID == existingTicektId)
            {
                _workorderList[index] = workorder;
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isExist)
        {
            _workorderList.Add(workorder);
        }

        ListEventChangeHandler();
    }

    public void ListEventChangeHandler()
    {
        _orderBtn = new Button[_workorderList.Count];
        int index = 0;
        int lastIndex = _orderBtn.Length;

        for (; index < lastIndex; index++)
        {
            Workorder workorder = _workorderList[index];
            _orderBtn[index] = new Button();
            _orderBtn[index].Name = String.Format("{0}", index);
            _orderBtn[index].Text = String.Format("Order #: {0} Source: {1} Desination: {2}", workorder.TicketID, workorder.PickupAddress, workorder.DropoffAddress);
            _orderBtn[index].BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
            _orderBtn[index].ForeColor = Color.White;
            _orderBtn[index].Font = new Font("Tahoma", 16, FontStyle.Regular);
            _orderBtn[index].Click += new EventHandler(OrderBtnClick);
        }

        UpdatePanel(_orderBtn);
    }

    public delegate void UpdateAcceptOrderPanel(Button[] btn);
    public void UpdatePanel(Button[] btn)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateAcceptOrderPanel updateMyPanel = new UpdateAcceptOrderPanel(UpdatePanel);
                this.Invoke(updateMyPanel, btn);
            }
            else
            {
                AddButtonOnPanel(btn);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public void AddButtonOnPanel(Button[] btn)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < btn.Length; index++)
        {
            this.acceptOrderPanle.Controls.Add(btn[index]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which line is showing you this error?

Comment: this.Invoke(updateMyPanel, btn);

Comment: Remove the surrounding try catch from that statement and check the results

Comment: Previously I did not add try-catch but because of error I did. Actually issues is that adding control from main form to panle. C# has specil UI thread so queston is that how to manage that thread so we can add controls on panle.

Comment: Can you try adding the InvokeRequired and this.Invoke statements in AddButtonOnPanel and check?

Comment: I tried but this.Invoke(updateMyPanel, btn);  statement has an error that ArgumentException was unhandled.

Comment: I found answer by myself.

Comment: Would you please post the solution for your problem so this might help someone in the future. You can post an aswer and then select it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good on delegates, but this is the way I would do your UpdatePanel method ...

```
public void UpdatePanel(Panel panel, Button button)
{
    if(panel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        panel.Invoke(new Action<Panel,Button>(UpdatePanel), new object[] {panel, button});
    }
    else
    {
        panel.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

hope this help ...

Comment: Same error Contrl.Invoke must be used to intreact with controls created on a seperate thread.